# cassandra/hadoop/pig design for loading and processing data

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

I have a setup of **Hadoop,Cassandra, Pig, Mysql**

My goal is to read 1 month data from cassandra process it and put result to mysql periodically.

**What is the best practice to do.?**
Is it i need to load all the data and filter in pig for 1 month or filter while loading from cassandra using pig/cql(using CqlStorage).

Here the problem is, 
if i need to filter while loading from cassandra **pig has a bug of having where clause** on cql(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6151).

or

problem with another solution of loading all data and filter through pig is, the data is too large nearly **200 million records**, is it a better solution to load all data, if so what about the performance and time taken by pig script to run.