# two store function in one pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a pig script to load , process and store the data.

If there are two store functions in the same single pig script, how it works?

```
a = load 'somefile' using PigStorage(',');
b ...
c ...
d ...
e = store d into 'output1';
f = store c into 'output2';
```

Does this run two times for each store. That is for **store 'e'** it process from **'a' to 'e'** and for **store 'f'** it directly store 'c' since it is already processed or it **will again start from 'a'** ?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking the underlying map/reduce framework has a multiple-output format so Pig can use that and run a two store script in a single job e.g. by having separate reduces and each would write to another file

However the actual map/reduce plan depends on what you do to get to c and d - sometimes that processing would require more than a single job - to understand how your script behave you can use Pig's [explain](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/test.html#explain) command. If you want a graphical visualization you can use [Netflix's lipstick](https://github.com/Netflix/Lipstick)

Comment: Thanks this helped me to understand the concept. And one more doubt i got here is if it taking more than a single job does it loads two times for each store, i mean to say does it load 'somefile' two times for each store 'e' and 'f'

Comment: It really depends on what you are doing. Usually Pig is smart enough not to load something twice if it can. As I said you should look at the plan before you let it run if that's important to you

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped me. Can you please suggest me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21698582/cassandra-hadoop-pig-design-for-loading-and-processing-data ,,, am sorry if am not supposed to ask this here but am need of help.